# .hover is not working to change the background color of an image

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an image be clicked and change the background color to yellow.

```
$('.Thunder').hover(function(){
    $('.Thunder').css('Background-color', ‘yellow’);
});
```

Comment: `.hover` (*is used to select elements when you mouse over them*) is not `.click`. Replace it with click event handler.

Comment: also, it's `background-color`. capitalisation is important. your `yellow` quotes are weird too. they should be single quotes.

Comment: also replace `$('.Thunder').css('Background-color', ‘yellow’);` with `$(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');`

Comment: you should change the title of your question to be searchable so other users in the future may come across it.

Answer (score -1):

Just like the comments say...try `click` instead of `hover`

```
$('.Thunder').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use `$(this)` to refer to the image clicked not all the images with `.Thunder` class.

Also pay attention to the capital `background`.

One more thing, **the single quotes** in OP seems to be problematic.

```
$('.Thunder').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```